# PHP error: Unable to Load Dynamic Library (memcache.so)

Tags: php, memcached

`error_log` shows the following line on startup:

> *Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/memcache.so' -
>   (null) in Unknown on line 0*

The file exists and it compiled properly. PHP version is 5.2.6. After Googling for a couple of hours I managed to find a couple of similar problems, but no solutions.

Comment: Have you tried to execute "ldd /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/memcache.so"?

Comment: I'm on OS X, so I here's what otool outputs: 
/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/memcache.so:
 /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
 /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 111.1.3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out that the easiest way to handle this was to update PHP to 5.2.8 with memcache via MacPorts. Everything is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well, and to solve it I had to install Ondrej's PPA of php, and then dist-upgrade to get the latest version of memcache.

[https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php](https://launchpad.net/%7Eondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php)